# Recurring eclipse hanging

Tags: eclipse

I use eclipse to do php development. I recently developed an issue where the IDE would hang, and immediately return to hanging whenever I opened eclipse.  It said it was hanging on "Initializing Java Tooling.  I reinstalled java and eclipse in multiple editions. I deleted my workspace.  I finally deleted the workspace and did a new checkout of my project, at with point it started working again.

Okay, so something screwed up in the project.  Fine.  I got it resetup, created a few files I need to run the project from the development directory using a local server (.user.ini and a php files), and was able to run it and make a couple changes.  Everything working.  I was adding a couple of files and noticed that the files I had manually created weren't showing in the package explorer, so I refresh at the root level and.... it hangs.

I eventually kill the app and on relaunch I can still work with the one file I had open, but whenever I reopened the project directory it hung.  I deleted the workspace and tried to recreate the project from the existing source, but after entering the source directory and hitting next, it hangs.

Am I doing something to the project directories that would cause eclipse to hang?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that eclipse was processing the sessions directory which I had configured to exist within the projects root directory.  Anytime I refreshed the tree it processed all the sessions files which apparently was enough to take 10+ minutes.  Weird.

After telling eclipse to exclude it, all is well again.

Update:

If you're having the same problem I had, then in eclipse you should be able to see a directory that is full of hundreds or thousands of text files.  Eclipse will try to process them.  To tell it not to, right click on the project, then click `properties -> resource -> resource filters`.  Add an exclude all rule where the name matches the folder name.  You may also want to do this for any .svn folders or the like.

Comment: Could you pl. tell me more? I'm facing a similar problem but not sure about where to find that sessions directory you've mentioned.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a few more details about my problem and specifics on fixing it.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @EricG please tell me where I can find the directory my eclipse hangs again and again

Comment: If you're having the same problem I had, then in eclipse you should be able to see a directory that is full of hundreds or thousands of text files.  In my case it was "~sessions" but I created that.  It will most likely be something you or someone else on the project configured yourself.  If you aren't sure, look through the files in eclipse.

Answer (score 39):

First try to clean your project and see if it solves the issue for you.

if not take a backup of .metadata folder(just in case you need to revert back) and delete the following directory:

`YOUR_WORKSPACE_HOME/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project`

or

`YOUR_WORKSPACE_HOME/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects`

restart Eclipse 
problem should be solved.

it solved things for me after wasting several hours on other solutions..

Comment: After doing this, Eclipse created a new .projects and got past the problem, but it didn't recognize any of my projects. I deleted the new .projects and then replaced it with the old one. Eclipse started, didn't hang and recognized all of my projects again.

Comment: Thanks. Both the answer and the comment were very helpful. I could restore my .projects directory except for one project that apparently did cause the troubles.

Comment: One other suggestion that worked for me just now.  If you have more than one project open, try closing all of them and opening them one by one until you find the offending project.  Then you can concentrate on fixing just that one instead of wiping them all out.

Comment: Instead of deleting the entire `.projects` folder, I deleted the following from within my project's folder inside the `.projects` folder: the `.indexes` folder and the `.syncinfo.snap` and `.markers.snap` files.

Comment: My problem was solved by renaming this folder (under the projects folder): `.org.eclipse.dltk.core.external.folders`. Then Eclipse complained on exit that it couldn't find the folder, so I recreated it manually (empty), and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 18):

For me, I fixed it by granting eclipse administrator rights and starting eclipse in cmd with:

```
eclipse.exe -clean -clearPersistedState
```

Comment: -clean -clearPersistedState worked for me, without admin rights

Comment: You made my day! Was also working without admin rights, and after that the GIT outline was working also for submodules, which was not working before for years.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thank you!

Comment: Still have to learn that lesson - never follow internet instructions without thinking. That removed all the configuration, layouts, styling I had. But on final step no hanging anymore :)

Comment: as @parvuselephantus said it reset every layout on eclise, however this is a great way to cleanup messy workspaces

Comment: Work for me as well. Thanks

Comment: This even worked for me on Mac. For mac users, command looks like:
open -a SpringToolSuite4.app --args -clean -clearPersistedState

Answer (score 1):

If you want help, go into your workspace, and look for the .metadata directory, then get the .log file and upload it.  You might have better luck getting responses from the Eclipse forums - http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/85/

My best guess is that there is some plugin that is causing problems, and storing state somewhere in the .metadata directory, but without a lot more information I can't tell what.  I have been doing PHP development in Eclipse, and I have not had this type of problem, although I did run into something similar with some really screwy SVN settings I once tried.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where to post this: there needs to be a generic "Eclipse Hanging" thread!

My issue was Eclipse hanging (on Windows) after a time ranging from a few moments to a few minutes after start-up.

Looking at the log file, "workspace.metadata.log", only pointed me in the wrong direction (removing random plugins pointed to by
stack traces).

I could have saved myself a lot of trouble by looking first at EventVwr, because it turned out to be a permissions problem in:

```
"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache"
```

Here is the error that appears in EventVwr:

```
taskhost (2404) WebCacheLocal: An attempt to open the file
"C:\Users\Malcolm.Boekhoff\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\V01.chk"
for read / write access failed with system error 5 (0x00000005): "Access is denied. ".
The open file operation will fail with error -1032 (0xfffffbf8).
```

Specifically, check the permissions on the "V01.log" file:

```
icacls "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache" /T
```

Fix it by adding yourself with full access:

```
icacls "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache" /T /Q /C /GRANT "%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%:F"
```

Further reading:

Here is the embarrassing list of time wasters that I tried thanks to Google. None of them worked:

```
- Disable: "Code Recommendations"
- Disable: "General"."Notifications" (used to be under "Mylyn")
- Disable: "Install/Update"."Automatic Updates"
- Disable: "Java"."Code Coverage"
- Disable: "News": "Preferences"."General"
- Remove the "org.eclipse.rse.*.jar" files, except for "org.eclipse.rse.shells.ui_3.0.500.201403271554.jar", from the "plugins" directory.
- Remove all maven jars
- Remove all gradle jars
- Specify: "-Declipse.log.level=ALL" in VM args (I think I forgot to also specify "-debug")
- etc.
```

If anyone is interested, here is my eclipse command line:

```
start "eclipse" /max "c:\eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\eclipse" -nosplash -clean -consoleLog -debug -data "c:\eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64\workspace" -product "org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product" -vm "c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java" "-vmargs" "-Declipse.log.level=ALL" "-Xmx2048m"
```

Here is the java console log that you see when you use "bin/java" (as above) instead of "bin/javaw":

```
Install location:
    file:/c:/eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/c:/eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/c:/eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/c:/eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.12.50.v20170928-1321.jar
Loading extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.1.0.v20170516-1513.jar
        eclipse.properties not found
Framework classpath:
    file:/c:/eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.12.50.v20170928-1321.jar
    file:/c:/eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/
    file:/c:/eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.1.0.v20170516-1513.jar
Debug options:
    file:/c:/mcb/religare/work/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 32
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry aft
er the state location is initialized.
Starting application: 5075
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: C:\eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configura
tion\logback.1.8.2.20171007-0217.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://1008.fwk985397764:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://1008.fwk985397764:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
Application Started: 10507
# !SESSION 2017-10-20 13:07:49.562
# version: 1.1
# verbose: true
# The following option strings are specified for this debug session:
| main | 2017-10-20 13:07:49.562 | org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench | /debug | org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.WorkbenchLogger | trace | 158 | Ignored attempt t
o set focus during set focus for: org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView@23f31375 |
```

Also, using "-debug", you get a file, "trace.log" in the .metadata directory (but no ".log" file, even with "ALL"):

```
# !SESSION 2017-10-20 13:07:49.562
# version: 1.1
# verbose: true
# The following option strings are specified for this debug session:
| main | 2017-10-20 13:07:49.562 | org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench | /debug | org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.WorkbenchLogger | trace | 158 | Ignored attempt to set focus during set focus for: org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView@23f31375 |
| main | 2017-10-20 13:09:47.775 | org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench | /debug | org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.WorkbenchLogger | trace | 158 | Ignored attempt to set focus during set focus for: org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView@d7b38cf |
| main | 2017-10-20 13:09:49.555 | org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench | /debug | org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.WorkbenchLogger | trace | 158 | Ignored attempt to set focus during set focus for: org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView@d7b38cf |
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having somewhat related problems with Eclipse for a few weeks now. In my case, I am trying to work on a PHP project on a PC and Mac and was finding Eclipse becoming very sluggish and then hanging completely on a regular basis on both machines. This behaviour seemed to be particularly bad when working on JavaScript files, but it was not limited to this. I tried various releases of Eclipse as well as 32 and 64 bit editions and could not get around it.

Ultimately, deleting the project (.project, .settings, .buildpath) and re-creating it seems to have solved the problem for me. (Note, my project is not stored in my workspace folder but elsewhere on a network drive.)

I know this isn't a direct answer to the above question and this question is a bit old now, but the title is consistent with what I experienced, so I'm throwing this out there in case anybody else stumbles upon it in a dark hour!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution when I selected `Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace` and selected the folders of previously broken worskpace to the new one. I got a semi-ready workspace which contained all settings I had previously, but it removed the error.

The only thing I needed to change was to give my svn repo credentials again upon next commit.

I made this after @tao's solution, when it did not solve the issue for me.