# Eclipse freezes a lot while developing android application, also the emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

While working in eclipse "Juno" and Android development kit on Ubuntu, It freezes a lot and I should wait for about 40 seconds to get it back. Why is that ??

It freezes when I build project, do some thing in the layout or views , submitting to git repo, running the emulator ( it freezes with no logcat entries written for a while, then i get all the messages at once)  and many other cases.

Does any one know why is that ?

Answer (score 3):

Try giving more memory to your eclipse. In your eclipse installation folder in the `eclipse.ini` file under the `-vmargs` option:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above process does not works for you then try this once

If you're having this problem, then in eclipse you should be able to see a directory that is full of hundreds or thousands of text files. Eclipse will try to process them. To tell it not to, right click on the project, then click properties -> resource -> resource filters. Add an exclude all rule where the name matches the folder name. You may also want to do this for any .svn folders or the like.

I found this answer in [Recurring eclipse hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902338/recurring-eclipse-hanging)