# InitRemoteEditJob is hanging

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

I have been trying to create a project in eclipse and there is a job called InitRemoteEditJob that is blocking everything. Its not even getting cancelled. 
Please suggest what to do?
[image]

Comment: I also have the same issue. I started eclipse with the following switches but still no luck:  -clean -clearPersistedState

Comment: The following worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902338/recurring-eclipse-hanging#answer-20342731

Comment: For me it was just a matter of cleaning eclipse and restarting. I think that works too.. Thanks a reply though.

Comment: Do we need to kill the process. I'd renamed and moved to new `Tomcat` because config. for that `Tomcat` frozen. Continuing that outside rename, rather `eclilpse config. correction`, this problem raised I hope. So Do I need to kill the process.

Comment: It had come up, I think after restart of `Eclipse`, Its remote desktop not observed, someone continuing the work when I see.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons of this bug.
You can try this:

```
./eclipse -clean -refresh -debug -data
```

I founded it here, it helped for me: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=335201#c1

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me but this is not a bug.  Rather your eclipse.ini is not configured correctly.

If your computer is 64bit then your eclipse.ini should look like this.

```
-vm
plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.1.v20231028-0937/jre/bin
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.600.v20231106-1826.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.800.v20231003-1442
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Xss2048k
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=19
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=19
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclientjava
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=17
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Declipse.e4.inject.javax.warning=false
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+useG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Djava.security.manager=allow
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=17
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Declipse.e4.inject.javax.warning=false
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=off
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-Xss2048k
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4g
-d64
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Djava.security.manager=allow
```